# Delete UITableView Rows in View Controller with multiple tableviews (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row, delete-row

I am trying to implement a delete row in one of a tableview in my viewcontroller that contains multiple UITableViews. My arrays are saved with NSUserDefaults.
Here is my code but I get the error `Index out of range` here is also a link for my project if anyone want to test it: https://files.fm/f/wv9uerhn

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

    if tableView == ScheduleTableView{

       // Here is my code but it gives me an error, first you need to add a row with the add button

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduleArray") ?? [String]()

        print(myarray)
        myarray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        ScheduleTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


    }

    if tableView == GoalsTableView{



    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually not saving the array with the deleted record to UserDefaults. Update your code to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
{
        if editingStyle == .delete {

        if tableView == ScheduleTableView{

           // Here is my code but it gives me an error, first you need to add a row with the add button

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            var myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "ScheduleArray") ?? [String]()

            print(myarray)
            myarray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            defaults.set(myarray, forKey: "ScheduleArray")
            ScheduleTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)


        }

        if tableView == GoalsTableView{



        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.